# Prove that the evaluation map $E_{x_0}: C(K) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be compact, and pick any $x_0 \in K$. Show that the function $E_{x_0}: C(K) \to \mathbb{R}, E(f) = f(x_0)$ is differentiable.

For functions between Euclidean spaces, I'm working with the definition that a function $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a linear transformation $L$ such that $$\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-L(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|}=0,$$ and I think I need to extend this somehow to the space $C(K)$ of continuous functions on $K$.

However, I'm quite lost on this one. It seems to me that I can't use the partial derivatives approach or have any other methods of showing differentiability apart from the definition from above. But since $E_{x_0}$ seems to be a linear transformation, do I just set $L = E_{x_0}$, so that the numerator becomes identically $0$?

This doesn't seem right to me, so if someone could let me know how to solve this one, it'd be greatly appreciated. I also can't see where the compactness of $K$ comes into play.

Comment: You're right - linear maps are always differentiable. In some sense, differentiability is measuring the property of being "locally linear".

Comment: @Dorebell, can you help me solve this problem then? I mean, if $E_{x_0}$ is a linear transformation, then it'd make sense for the derivative to just be the representation of $E_{x_0}$ itself, wouldn't it? But again, I fail to see the significance of $K$ being compact, and it seems that this would then be almost too easy. So I'm thinking it might not be quite right to just say $L = E_{x_0}$, making the numerator $0$.

Comment: It is right. $K$ is only assumed to be compact to ensure that $C(K)$ with the sup norm is a normed vector space (even Banach space), because each continuous function in $K$ is bounded.

Comment: @PhoemueX, great, thanks aplenty!